Why is the embedding $\begin{bmatrix} k & k \\ 0 & k \end{bmatrix} \hookrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} k & k \\ k & k \end{bmatrix}$ an epimorphism?
Let $k$ be a field, $ \Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} k & k \\ 0 & k \end{bmatrix} $ be the upper triangular $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix ring, and $ A = \begin{bmatrix} k & k \\ k & k \end{bmatrix} $ be the full $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix ring.
There is a natural embedding ring homomorphism
$$
i : \Lambda \longrightarrow A
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}.
$$
My question is:

Why is $ i $ an epimorphism? That is, if $ \Lambda \xrightarrow{i} A \overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightrightarrows}} B $ are morphisms in the category of rings, and $ f \cdot i = g \cdot i $, then $ f = g $.

If we use the equivalent conditions of an epimorphism in the category of rings, for example, $ i : \Lambda \longrightarrow A $ is an epimorphism if and only if the restriction functor $ i_* : A\text{-mod} \longrightarrow \Lambda\text{-mod} $ is fully faithful, then we can easily see that the functor $ i_* $ is fully faithful, and therefore $ i : \Lambda \longrightarrow A $ is an epimorphism. However, I do not want to use this equivalent condition or any other equivalent conditions. I want to show that $ i $ is an epimorphism strictly using the definition; that is, if $ \Lambda \xrightarrow{i} A \overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightrightarrows}} B $ are morphisms in the category of rings, and $ f \cdot i = g \cdot i $, then $ f = g $.
Strictly following the definition of an epimorphism, I couldn’t prove it, so I’m seeking help. Thank you!
Here are some additional details.
According to Corollary 9 on page 5 of the paper Ring Epimorphisms from Path Algebras to Matrix Algebras, since $A$ is a finitely generated module over $\Lambda$, the map $i : \Lambda \longrightarrow A$ is an epimorphism if and only if the restriction functor $i_* : A\text{-mod} \longrightarrow \Lambda\text{-mod}$ is fully faithful, where $A\text{-mod}$ and $\Lambda\text{-mod}$ are the categories of finitely generated modules over $A$ and $\Lambda$, respectively.
The following argument shows that $i_* : A\text{-mod} \longrightarrow \Lambda\text{-mod}$ is fully faithful:

Take finitely generated modules $M$ and $N$ over $A$. We then show that we have the isomorphism $i_* : \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}(M,N)$. Since $A$ is a semisimple algebra and has only one indecomposable module $\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ up to isomorphism, it is sufficient to show that
$$
i_* : \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
is an isomorphism.


Take $0 \neq h \in \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$, then $i_*(h) = h \neq 0 \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$. So $i_* : \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is injective.


And we can compute that
$$
\dim_k\left(\operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \simeq k\right) = 1 = \dim_k\left(\operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \simeq k\right),
$$
which confirms that for any $u \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$, it must be a scalar multiplication map, i.e., $u = \kappa \cdot (-)$ for some $\kappa \in k$. Since any scalar multiplication map is also a homomorphism in $\operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$, we deduce that $\kappa \cdot (-) \in \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$.
Thus, applying $i_*$, we have $i_*(\kappa \cdot (-)) = \kappa \cdot (-) = u$, which shows that $i_* : \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is surjective.


Consequently, $i_*: \operatorname{Hom}_A\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\Lambda}\left(\begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k \\ k \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is an isomorphism, and therefore $i_*$ is fully faithful.


@Anne Bauval Thank you! I have provided additional details above explaining why $i_*$ is fully faithful.

This can be deduced from the Silver-Mazet-Isbell Zigzag Theorem: if $S$ is a subring of $B$, then the set of all elements of $B$ with the property that any pair of morphisms from $B$ that agree on $S$ also agree on those elements (the dominion of $S$ in $B$) consists precisely of all elements that can be written in the form $XYZ$, where $X$ is a row vector, $Z$ is a column vector, $Y$ is a matrix, the entries of $X$ and $Z$ are in $B$, and the entries of $XY$, $Y$, and $YZ$ are in $S$. See this post for references.
This suggests coming up with a Zigzag (and in this case I thought it very likely that taking $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ as elements will suffice).
Suppose $f,g\colon A\to B$ agree on $\Lambda$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{array}\right) &= f\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\ 
1&0
\end{array}\right)\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\ 
1&0\end{array}\right) f\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\ 
0&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\ 
1&0
\end{array}\right)\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0\end{array}\right) f\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
g\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)
g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 &1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right) f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= f\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right) g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= f\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\\
&= g\left( \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right)\\
&= g\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Since $f$ and $g$ also agree on matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \lambda
\end{array}\right)$, it follows that $f$ and $g$ agree on all matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & d\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
c & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
Therefore they agree on their sum, and hence agree on all of $A$.
Note that it is an epimorphism in the category of unital rings with unital morphisms, the category of rings with unity and morphisms that are not necessarily unital, and the category of Rngs.
